# Grav GitSync saving in wrong location

Tags: git, grav

In grav, I set up git sync to an existing repository. I am trying to have it sync changes to pages when they are made in the admin panel, however, when i save, instead of saving under the /user/ folder, it created its own pages folder on the same level. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You have to add more details about issue, it's now unclear. "...it created its own pages folder" - there it "created"? How you configured GitSync (which folders included in repo)?

Answer (score 0):

1. GitSync can sync only folders inside `/user/` root (never tried to select the whole `user`) and *if* you'll add more than single folder in configuration, GitSync *may* select common-base parent as root of repo (have to check it)
2. If you have something like

   folders:

   - pages

only in `user/config/plugins/git-sync.yaml`, when `pages` will be at first level of [repo](https://github.com/UrsineCorner/whyhq) with pages (as expected, I have such site+repo gitsync'ed)

If it isn't your case, lets inspect you configuration in details

Comment: I used the gitsync wizard to set it up, and had it sync only the pages folder. To clarify: my folder structure is normally like your example
Users:
        pages

however once i git sync it creates a new folder called pages on the same level as users.

along with that the only thing in my gitsync.yaml is 
enabled:true

Comment: @Charlie - well, *show* relevant to sync-areas part of your config and URL (or screenshot of repo-root for private repo) of resulting repo